# Random vector generation in verilog

Tags: verilog

I need to generate random 1023 bit vectors in Verilog. I need something that I can put in the testbench to generate such vectors and feed these vectors to the design under test

Comment: But $random only generates a 32 bit random vector . One possible solution would be to concatenate the 32 bit vectors to form a 1024 bit vector and then use that . However , I was wondering if there is anything better that we can do ? Since the 32 bit random vector is based on a pseudo test vector generation , the vectors will start repeating after roughly 2/3( 2^32) and I need over 2 billion codewords/vectors for my applicaiton

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39406/generate-an-n-bit-random-number-in-verilog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, concatenated calls to `$random` might serve your purpose unless you really need to avoid the 32-bit periodicity (which might still be possible via `$random` but Im not sure how best to do it if possible).

Better would be to use some SystemVerilog constructs, namely random classes:

```
class myVector;
   rand bit [1022:0] vec; // 1023 bits
endclass
...
myVector vec = new;
vec.randomize();
getRandomVector <= vec.vec;
vec.randomize();
getAnotherRandomVector <= vec.vec;
```

If you want to ensure no repeats from multiple calls to `.randomize()`, you can declare `vec` to be `randc` instead (you can read more on the exact differences in IEEE 1800-2012 Ch 18). You can also provide constraints on the randomization to only get vectors of a certain form if you need it (like limit the number of 1s or anything like that).

Comment: Short note, if you are requiring strict control over your random variables, you really should use these SystemVerilog constructs as they were added to the language for exactly this reason!